# A Schema is required to be provided to GraphQLView

Tags: django, graphql

I was following [this](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-plain/) tutorial to integrate Graphql with Django, I did everything according to that tutorial when I'm hitting graphql URL on my local machine

> http://localhost:8000/graphql

I'm geting the following error

> AssertionError at /graphql
>
> A Schema is required to be provided to GraphQLView.

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/graphql
Django Version: 1.11.1
Exception Type: AssertionError
Exception Value:
A Schema is required to be provided to GraphQLView.
Exception Location: /home/psingh/Projects/django_graphql/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphene_django/views.py in **init**, line 84
Python Executable:  /home/psingh/Projects/django_graphql/env/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:
['/home/psingh/Projects/django_graphql/project',
 '/home/psingh/Projects/django_graphql/env/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/psingh/Projects/django_graphql/env/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/psingh/Projects/django_graphql/env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/psingh/Projects/django_graphql/env/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/psingh/Projects/django_graphql/env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/psingh/Projects/django_graphql/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/psingh/Projects/django_graphql/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 12 May 2017 12:18:31 +0000

In settings.py

```
GRAPHENE = {
'SCHEMA': 'project.schema.schema'
```

}

project> schema.py

```
import graphene
import mainapp.schema 
class Query(mainapp.schema.Query, graphene.ObjectType):
  # This class will inherit from multiple Queries
  # as we begin to add more apps to our project
  pass

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

app>schema.py

```
import graphene
from graphene_django.types import DjangoObjectType
from cookbook.ingredients.models import Category, Ingredient

class CategoryType(DjangoObjectType):
  class Meta:
     model = Category


 class IngredientType(DjangoObjectType):
   class Meta:
      model = Ingredient


 class Query(graphene.AbstractType):
   all_categories = graphene.List(CategoryType)
   all_ingredients = graphene.List(IngredientType)

   def resolve_all_categories(self, args, context, info):
     return Category.objects.all()

  def resolve_all_ingredients(self, args, context, info):
     # We can easily optimize query count in the resolve method
     return Ingredient.objects.select_related('category').all()
```

project_urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView
import schema

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^graphql', GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True)),
   url(r'^', include('mainapp.urls')),    

]
```

Any help would be great.I am new to the coding stuff.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add the schema to your `settings.py` as seen [here](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-plain/):

`GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'cookbook.schema.schema'
}`

You need 2 `schema.py` files, one at the root level of the project and one in the app folder.

Comment: I have added that as GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'project.schema.schema'
}

Comment: I have edited the question with all the required codes.

Answer (score 5):

if you don't want to add `GRAPHENE` variable in `settings.py` then you can pass `scheme` parameter in `GraphQLView.as_view()` method call

```
   from onlineshop_project.scheme import schema
   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
       url(r'^graphql', GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True, schema=schema)),
   ]
```

You can check [the documentation](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-plain/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you added "graphene_django" in INSTALLED_APPS under settings.py file ?
Check here - https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-plain/#update-settings

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to be different than the accepted answer. Also, the question was asked and answered 3 years ago. Be sure to look at the date of the original question when answering. Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).